# Is there a way to make the CSS to recognize 100% to include the paddings, margins and border?

Tags: css, html

I have a the following html code:

```
<div class="panel">Some Text Here</div>
```

With the following css attached

```
.panel{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Because the panel has a border it's causing the vertical scrollbar to appear, is there a way to make the CSS to recognize 100% to include the paddings, margins and border?

Comment: Height **does** include border and padding. Not margin though, no.

Comment: I need it to include everything in both Width and Height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you're targeting CSS3 you can use the [`box-sizing` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing)

Of course, only newer browser support it, and even then they don't support it directly (yet), so you have to use the browser specific version (e.g. `-moz-box-sizing`)

```
.panel{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid black;

    box-sizing: border-box;         // IE8, Opera
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    // Firefox
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; // Chrome
}
```

Comment: IE8 and Opera support `box-sizing`; you don't need `-ms-box-sizing` (that's what IE8 *would* have required, but MS decided to support unprefixed CSS3 properties when the relevant CSS3 module had reached Candidate Recommendation status or later, which `box-sizing`'s CSS3UI module has been at for ages).

Comment: IE8 isn't recognizing neither the inline-block nor the box-sizing... stupid explorer